# RECOMPILE function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, recompile

We had a production level event over the weekend where execution of a function suddenly went from MS to nearly a minute.

Unfortunately, SQL wasn't able to execute the ALTER Function and it kept 'spinning' due to the high volume of queries calling the function and the CPU hit critical 100% and the database became unusable/instable.

Ultimately the fastest resolution was to reboot the server.

However, is there a better/faster way to force the RECOMPILE that wouldn't hang?

I've found a number of articles on RECOMPILE but nothing along the lines of the hanging and being blocked.

Attempts to KILL the individual queries resulted in whack-a-mole and couldn't clear them out fast enough.

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 SP3

Comment: Did you [look at wait stats](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/troubleshooting/wait-stats-capture-script/) before rebooting the server?  What diagnostics did you run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...Ultimately the fastest resolution was to reboot the server.
>   ...Attempts to KILL the individual queries resulted in whack-a-mole
>   and couldn't clear them out fast enough.

There is no need to `reboot` server or `kill` sessions manually when you want to have an exclusive access to database, you can use `ALTER DATABASE ... SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` and than issue your `ALTER FUNCTION`.

To remove individual plan from cache you can use `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE(plan_handle)` with the `plan_handle` you are interested in, see *Example A. Clearing a query plan from the plan cache* here [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: In a perfect world I agree that would allow the ALTER FUNCTION/DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to execute.  Unfortunately, I suspectnot all of our apps are self-aware enough to reconnect once the SET MULTI_USER is executed.  I will give it a try if there is a next time.  Thanks